# Кнопка в родительском блоке ссылка

Tags: css, css3, button, href, click

Есть блок-ссылка с инфой, при клике на которую можно перейти на другую страницу, но в этом же блоке есть еще и кнопка, которая открывает модальное окно. Проблема заключается в том, что кнопка не кликабельная а при клике на нее сразу срабатывает родительский блок-ссылка. Как сделать ее кликабельной?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо на кнопку повесить обработчик и запретить всплытие события с помощью `stopPropagation()`. Ссылка: https://jsfiddle.net/pab9g0zx/2/

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так

```
<a href="#" id="somelink">
  Ссылка
  <button>button</button>
  Ссылка
</a>

<script>
  document.getElementById('somelink').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if(event.target && event.target.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
      event.preventDefault()
      // .. тут открываешь модальное окно
    }
  });
</script>
```

Но если честно, то какую-то очень странную хрень ты придумал

Comment: Это не я это дизайнер придумал. Спасибо

Comment: Дизайнер не должен придумывать тебе html-код. Я не глядя на макет почти уверен, что можно избежать подобных клоунов с вертолётами. Но если нельзя, то в рыло давать таким дизайнерам нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно всё-таки не класть кнопку в ссылку:

```css
section {
  height: 4em;
  width: 16em;
}

a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button {
  float: right;
  margin: .5em;
  height: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 1em);
}

a:hover {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <button>Button</button>
  <a></a>
</section>
```